# Converting rational number to string

Tags: haskell, rational-number

I have the following requirements: given a rational number (x % y):

1. If y != 1 => return "x y"
2. Otherwise: return "x"

The following function works:

```
import Data.Ratio

my_show :: (Integral a, Show a)  => (Ratio a) -> String
my_show rat = let x = numerator rat
                  y = denominator rat in
                if y /= 1 then (show x) ++ " " ++ (show y) else show x
```

Is it possible to make it more elegant? For example, I saw in the sources of Data.Ratio that it uses some notation for functions inputs: `(x:%y)`, but it didn't work for me. So I have to use `let` and explicitly call `numerator` and `denominator`.

Comment: Hi @user4035, this question seems like would receive better answers at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @user4035 I don’t see any way to make this function clearer than it already is — I would probably write it pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a significant difference, but slightly closer to your written specification (and more "haskellish" phrasing).

```
my_show r | y /= 1    = show x ++ " " ++ show y
          | otherwise = show x
    where
    x = numerator r
    y = denominator r
```

We could lose the variables in the where clause if a suitable [pattern synonym](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/pattern-synonyms) were specified: `my_show (x :% y) | ...` . If `Data.Ratio` were written nowadays that would probably be available.  But it's an old library, so if you want that pattern synonym, you'll have to write it yourself.